# removing pairs of elements from numpy arrays that are NaN (or another value) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have an array with two columns in numpy. For example:

```
a = array([[1, 5, nan, 6],
           [10, 6, 6, nan]])
a = transpose(a)
```

I want to efficiently iterate through the two columns, a[:, 0] and a[:, 1] and remove any pairs that meet a certain condition, in this case if they are NaN.  The obvious way I can think of is:

```
new_a = []
for val1, val2 in a:
  if val2 == nan or val2 == nan:
    new_a.append([val1, val2])
```

But that seems clunky.  What's the pythonic numpy way of doing this?

thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to take only the rows that have no NANs, this is the expression you need:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a[~np.isnan(a).any(1)]
array([[  1.,  10.],
       [  5.,   6.]])
```

If you want the rows that do not have a specific number among its elements, e.g. 5:

```
>>> a[~(a == 5).any(1)]
array([[  1.,  10.],
       [ NaN,   6.],
       [  6.,  NaN]])
```

The latter is clearly equivalent to

```
>>> a[(a != 5).all(1)]
array([[  1.,  10.],
       [ NaN,   6.],
       [  6.,  NaN]])
```

**Explanation**:
Let's first create your example input

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 5, np.nan, 6],
...               [10, 6, 6, np.nan]]).transpose()
>>> a
array([[  1.,  10.],
       [  5.,   6.],
       [ NaN,   6.],
       [  6.,  NaN]])
```

This determines which elements are NAN

```
>>> np.isnan(a)
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

This identifies which rows have any element which are True

```
>>> np.isnan(a).any(1)
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Since we don't want these, we negate the last expression:

```
>>> ~np.isnan(a).any(1)
array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

And finally we use the boolean array to select the rows we want:

```
>>> a[~np.isnan(a).any(1)]
array([[  1.,  10.],
       [  5.,   6.]])
```

Comment: +1: Super clear and helpful explanation, and I like ~np.isnan as it spells out what you are doing.

Comment: What an awesome answer

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the array into a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), and use the [`compress_rows` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#to-a-ndarray):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 5, np.nan, 6],
           [10, 6, 6, np.nan]])
a = np.transpose(a)
print(a)
# [[  1.  10.]
#  [  5.   6.]
#  [ NaN   6.]
#  [  6.  NaN]]
b=np.ma.compress_rows(np.ma.fix_invalid(a))
print(b)
# [[  1.  10.]
#  [  5.   6.]]
```

Comment: +1: wow!  I don't often see masked arrays being used and suggested!  Good one!

Answer (score 3):

Not to detract from ig0774's answer, which is perfectly valid and Pythonic and is in fact the normal way of doing these things in plain Python, but: numpy supports a boolean indexing system which could also do the job.

```
new_a = a[(a==a).all(1)]
```

I'm not sure offhand which way would be more efficient (or faster to execute).

If you wanted to use a different condition to select the rows, this would have to be changed, and precisely how depends on the condition. If it's something that can be evaluated for each array element independently, you could just replace the `a==a` with the appropriate test, for example to eliminate all rows with numbers larger than 100 you could do

```
new_a = a[(a<=100).all(1)]
```

But if you're trying to do something fancy that involves all the elements in a row (like eliminating all rows that sum to more than 100), it might be more complicated. If that's the case, I can try to edit in a more specific answer if you want to share your exact condition.

Comment: +1: for vectorized approach. this is almost always faster and is one the main reasons for using numpy.

Answer (score 2):

I think  [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) should do this. E.g.,

```
new_a = [(val1, val2) for (val1, val2) in a if math.isnan(val1) or math.isnan(val2)]
```

Comment: You'd actually need to make the test something like `val1 != val1` because `nan == nan` returns false. But +1.

Comment: I edited the above... honestly, I never have had need of `NaN`, so I was mostly addressing the form of building a list. Based on the documentation here: http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.isnan, I think this ought to work...

Comment: shouldn't it be:

... in a where not math isnan(val1) and not math.isnan(val2)?

Comment: You're been doing too much SQL.  :)  Use 'if' instead of 'where'.